# D-like slices of immutable data in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, d, slice

Does OCaml have slices (like D slices of immutable data)?  It seems like it would fit really nicely into the OCaml paradigm (you could avoid constantly having to reverse a list every time you want to do any kind of processing with tail recursion, because you can access/slice the list from both ends).  Would it be difficult to implement?

As an example, if OCaml lists behaved like slices, I could say

```
let merge lhs rhs =
  merge_helper lhs rhs []

let rec merge_helper lhs rhs res = 
    match lhs with
    | [] -> res ^ rhs
    | l_first :: l_rest ->
        match rhs with
        | [] -> res ^ lhs
        | r_first :: r_rest ->
        if l_first <= r_first then
            merge_helper l_rest rhs (res ^ [l_first])
        else
            merge_helper lhs r_rest (res ^ [r_first])
```

Where lhs ^ rhs attempts to concatenate them by copying rhs into the space next to lhs (if available) and otherwise copies them into a new slot in memory at least twice as large as lhs.

EDIT: Perhaps I need to clarify
Concatenation such as let concatted = lhs ^ rhs is not a mutating operation.  lhs will be the same as it was, and rhs will be the same as it was. concatted may or may not point to the same segment of memory as lhs (just with a larger length).  The copying I was talking about is an "under-the-hood" operation.  From the client's perspective all objects behave as if they were immutable and the construction lhs ^ rhs takes amortized O(|rhs|) time (amortized in the sense that if we keep on constructing longer slices by repeatedly concatenating things on the right, the number of internal re-allocations is small).

EDIT 2: Sorry, I was imagining that concatenating behaves like D appending.  D doesn't do this because they also allow slices of mutable data, but in OCaml things default to immutable, so this wouldn't be a problem (at least, no more than it is for D lists).

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand what lists are. You seem to consider that a list is just like a c++ vector (I don't know D's slices but from what I have found, it looks like a c++ vector) but with more restrictions.

It is not! A list is **immutable**, **persistent** and  gives **constant time cons (::)** and it is impossible to achieve this with an array (even with a smart array that you call slice).

example of thing you can do with lists but not with arrays:

```
let l = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
let a = 0 :: l
let b = 1 :: l
```

the last two lines are constant time (no matter the size of `l`) and add constant space.

Comment: You *can* go the other direction and make a list have (amortized) the performance of a double-sided queue.  See Chris Okasaki's work for details. http://www.amazon.com/Purely-Functional-Structures-Chris-Okasaki/dp/0521663504

Comment: I know what a list is, but as you admit, you don't know what a slice is.  A D slice is immutable (if the type is labeled immutable), persistent and has amortized constant time appending, so it does match everything you said.  The big difference between a D slice and an array is that slices do not own the memory they reference so it is possible to have multiple slices which point to overlapping memory.  Please read up on D slices before jumping to conclusions: http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html

Comment: @dspyz I have read this page before writing my answer and it says `If [some data has already been concatenated], a new array block is allocated that will hold the existing and new data`, which is not the way lists work and is undesirable in the example of my answer. So as I have already said, D slices don't have constant time cons. And if we love lists it is precisely because they offer constant time cons.

Comment: @Thomash I'm sorry, I didn't look carefully enough at your example.  You're right that D slices don't work for situations where you want multiple lists to share the same tail (ie something like making a table of Collatz sequences), however I find that it's much more common for each tail to have at most one head.  In that case slices are much more flexible (and also more time and space efficient)

Comment: @BlackVegetable Is this a good book? I'm tempted to get it for my kindle.

Comment: @dspyz I've only read excerpts from it thus far.  I too am tempted to purchase it.